# How to prevent using UIAppearance with UIView's tintColor from changing all UITabBar icon colours?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitabbar, uiappearance

If I perform `UIView.appearance().tintColor = ...` the tintColor of all the icons in the tab bar change from the normal inactive grey state to whatever I set the tint color to.

I don't understand why this is the case. I'm just changing the tint color of the app, and by default the tint color doesn't mess with making all the tab bar icons look active at once.

How do I stop it from doing this? I want the tint color to change, but the unselected tabs to retain an inactive color.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you've found a solution by now, but here's my two cents anyway.

Interface Builder doesn't use the UIAppearance API anywhere (as far as I am aware). It does, however, set properties on certain objects, to be applied to them as they're instantiated.

There is a "Global Tint" property in the File Inspector which controls the top-level default `tintColor`. It is worth noting that, unless explicitly told a different color to use (whether via `UIView.appearance()` or just `UIView.tintColor`) child views inherit their `tintColor` from their parent views. Remember, this chain continues up through the view hierarchy until it hits something that has a `tintColor`. Usually, it's the `UIWindow` it ends up hitting, and that has the default blue color of which Apple is so fond. Any dimming or temporary recoloring for state is inherited either from the view itself, or a close ancestor. This is important to note.

It is also good to note that you can respond to this in `UIViewController` by overriding the `tintColorChanged()` method, which gets called whenever this happens. By messing with `UIView.appearance()`, you effectively disable the chain of inheritance for every view in the hierarchy, and you let each fend for itself for its own colors. In my mind, there are at least two ways that this might prevent a `UITabBar` from properly representing a tab's state:

First, the tab bar has tinted image views under the hood, which inherit their tint color from the parent `UITabBar`. Even if they could get state-specific colors from the tab bar, the poor thing wouldn't have anything different to tell them, other than, "**You were given a color, and you will respect that color!**", followed by a slap and a sound flogging, at which point they would sulk back, knowing no more than before. By disabling the hierarchical `tintColor` inheritance system, you disable state. That's not good. Don't do that.

Second, by setting the tint color for *every* `UIView` *regardless of state*, you have told the tab bar items to hold that color *regardless of state*. That's not good. Don't do that either.

If you're using Interface Builder (or Storyboards if you prefer), I'd recommend setting that global tint color in the File Inspector, and leaving it at that. This would still set your tint color the way you want, while saving these poor views from domestic abuse.

If you need screenshots of where to find the File Inspector or the Global Tint option, I'd suggest poking around that sidebar on the right in Xcode. A little poking around never hurt anybody (except in movies).

Comment: This is amazing! Been using UIView.appearance().tintColor for years for styling, but it always felt a bit hacky (not to mention weird problems with tint colors) and now I know why. This feels so much more correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say you're "changing the tint color of the app"?

The `UIView` appearance proxy is doing exactly what you told it to. You asked it to set the `tintColor` of ALL `UIView`s in your app, which includes those views inside your `UITabBar`.

It sounds like you don't actually want to alter the `tintColor` of all `UIView`s, but instead want to target a specific subset. You should look into `appearanceForTraitCollection` or the (now deprecated) `appearanceWhenContainedIn` methods.

Comment: No, when I set the appearance of all views using the storyboard inspector it doesn't set unselected UITabBarItems to grey. I just want it to set the active ones, as the default app behaviour does.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. you should post some code.

Comment: The code in the original post is the only code required to reproduce this. By default, iOS sets the global tint color to blue. Everywhere it's blue active states. When you have a tab bar, the icons are blue when selected, and have an inactive grey color when not selected. I want to change this behaviour to, say, red. My impression is to use the code in the original question, but it sets the unselected state of tab bars as well, while default behaviour does not. My question is how do I prevent this?

Comment: It sounds like you're assuming the storyboard inspector uses `UIView.appearance()` under the hood. I'm almost certain that is not true. Do you have any evidence to back that up? Per Apple's docs on UIAppearance "Use the UIAppearance protocol to get the appearance proxy for a class. You can customize the appearance of instances of a class by sending appearance modification messages to the class’s appearance proxy." Altering the tintColor on UIView's appearance proxy affects every UIView in your application, including those that compose your tab bar. Its a ham-fisted non-solution to your problem